# How to cut up my dataframe in chunks, but keeping groups together

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a massive set of datasets. I have a set for each year in the 2000's. I take a combination of three years and run a code on that to clean.
The problem is that due to the size I can't run my cleaning code on it as my Memory runs out.
I was thinking about splitting the data using something like:

```
 df.ix[1,N/x]
```

Where N is the total amount of rows in my dataframe. I think I should replace the dataframe to clear up the memory being used. This does mean I have to load in the dataframe first for each chunk I create.

There are several problems:
How do I get N when N can be different for each year ?
The operation requires that groups of data stay together.
Is there a way to make x vary with the size of N?

Is all of this highly inefficient/is there an efficient inbuild function for this?

Dataframe looks like:

```
 ID     Location    year  other variables
 1         a        2006
 1         a        2007
 1         b        2006
 1         a        2005
 2         c        2005
 2         c        2007
 3         d        2005
```

What I need is for all the same ID's to stay together. 
The data to be cut in managable chunks, dependent on a yearly changing total amount of data. 
In this case it would be:

```
 ID     Location    year  other variables
 1         a        2006
 1         a        2007
 1         b        2006
 1         a        2005

 ID     Location    year  other variables
 2         c        2005
 2         c        2007
 3         d        2005
```

The data originates from a csv by year. So all 2005 data comes from 2005csv, 2006 data from 2006csv  etc.
The csv's are loaded into memory and concatenated to form one set of three years.
The individual csv files have the same setup as indicated above. So each observation is stated with an ID, location and year, followed by a lot of other variables.

Running it just on a group by group bases would be a bad idea, as there are thousands, if not millions of these ID's. They can have dozens of locations and a maximum of three years. All of this needs to stay together.

Loops on this many rows take ages in my experience

I was thinking maybe something along the lines of:
create a variable that counts the number of groups
use the maximum of this count variable and divide it by 4 or 5.
cut the data up in chunks this way
Not sure if this would be efficient, even less sure how to execute it.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me how your data is formatted, but did you try simple loops (at least it would give you a first working setup that you can then try to speed up)?
You start loading you file line by line until the index changes and tell us how slow this is. It might even be sufficient since once the 1st set is loaded you can work on it while loading the 2nd one...

Comment: When you say chunks, do you mean splitting the data into "chunks of rows"? How is your data stored locally/remotely? If it is something like csv or tsv, the best approach would be to iterate through it, and bin every row according to the ID. If you give me an example of what your raw data looks like I can try to post an answer.

Comment: By chunks I do mean chunks of rows. Rest: see edit above

Comment: Can you give an example (definintion) of a chunck that would be a valid unit to process? Also, to do the data cleansing, do you need all of the _other_ variables, or just a subset?

Comment: I need all other variables. As shown above, any chunk that does not cut up an ID set will be valid. Pereferably as many ID's at the same time, but never seperate one ID row from another with the same ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be like as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# generating random DF
num_rows = 100

locs = list('abcdefghijklmno')

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'id': np.random.randint(1, 100, num_rows),
         'location': np.random.choice(locs, num_rows),
         'year': np.random.randint(2005, 2007, num_rows)})

df.sort_values('id', inplace=True)

print('**** sorted DF (first 10 rows) ****')
print(df.head(10))

# chopping DF into chunks ...
chunk_size = 5

chunks = [i for i in df.id.unique()[::chunk_size]]

chunk_margins = [(chunks[i-1],chunks[i]) for i in range(1, len(chunks))]

df_chunks = [df.ix[(df.id >= x[0]) & (df.id < x[1])] for x in chunk_margins]

print('**** first chunk ****')
print(df_chunks[0])
```

Output:

```
**** sorted DF (first 10 rows) ****
    id location  year
31   2        c  2005
85   2        e  2006
89   2        l  2006
70   2        i  2005
60   4        n  2005
68   7        g  2005
22   7        e  2006
73  10        i  2005
23  10        j  2006
47  16        n  2005

**** first chunk ****
    id location  year
31   2        c  2005
85   2        e  2006
89   2        l  2006
70   2        i  2005
60   4        n  2005
68   7        g  2005
22   7        e  2006
73  10        i  2005
23  10        j  2006
47  16        n  2005
6   16        k  2006
82  16        g  2005
```

Answer (score 2):

Use chunked pandas by importing Blaze.
Instructions from http://blaze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ooc.html

---

Naive use of Blaze triggers out-of-core systems automatically when called on large files.

```
d = Data('my-small-file.csv')  
d.my_column.count()  # Uses Pandas  

d = Data('my-large-file.csv')  
d.my_column.count()  # Uses Chunked Pandas
```

**How does it work?**
Blaze breaks up the data resource into a sequence of chunks. It pulls one chunk into memory, operates on it, pulls in the next, etc.. After all chunks are processed it often has to finalize the computation with another operation on the intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for Blaze solution - it looks very promising for my projects